# Travel from New York Port authority to Brookhaven National lab via bus( or any cheap method)?

Tags: trains, buses, new-york-city

I have a chance to visit Brookhaven National lab for the remaining summer, but I am not very good with traveling. How would I get a bus to Brookhaven National lab from the New York Port Authority (8th Ave)? I am planning a round trip.

I depart 7/31/16 and will be in the New York port authority at 3:35pm or 9:30pm  and have to return home at 8/19/16, being at the New York port authority at either 6:00am or 12:30pm respectively.  I do not think the depart and leave dates can be changed, as my housing is fixed.

The least amount of exchanges via bus/train/whatever cheap would be preferred. Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be a bus?  The Long Island Railroad stops at Yaphank which is close to BNL.

Comment: oh I guess not, as long as I get to point A to point B. My funds are not too great.

Comment: You might want to ask your contacts at the lab, or, if you're being accommodated in someone's home, ask your host, for directions.  There are several train stations within driving distance and they may be willing to pick you up, in which case you should take whatever train they tell you to take.  If you cannot get a ride from the station, you'll need to take a taxi, in which case you will want to go to the Mastic/Shirley station, which is the closest station (according to https://www.bnl.gov/staffservices/othertransportation.php).

Comment: Institutions such as Brookhaven will have a section of the website for visitors. There is a free [shuttle to the Ronkonkoma LIRR station](https://www.bnl.gov/staffservices/shuttleservices.php) for visitors and guests, but it only operates twice daily and must be reserved in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the [Hampton Jitney bus](https://www.hamptonjitney.com/PDFS/MN_EB_20160707.pdf) (no relation) every 15-30 minutes all day from Manhattan to Manorville, then a taxi back to Brookhaven National Laboratory. The taxi fare may be quite a bit cheaper this way than from Ronkonkoma as the distance is shorter. It may also be faster, depending on time of day, since the bus has only one stop between Manhattan and Manorville.

The bus picks up at 40th and Lexington, so you'll have to go crosstown several blocks from Port Authority; either take the 7/7X from Times Square/42nd St to Grand Central Terminal, or walk it.

Comment: So this bus runs daily then, at all hours?

Comment: @RoSiv Did you not read the linked timetable?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize there was one. Thanks. So ii read this right  I could depart at 5:40pm and arrive at manorville at about 8:00pm, given it be a Sunday?

Answer (score 1):

I messaged my advisor and she informed me that I would need to take the train from Penn station to Ronkonkoma and then Taxi to BNL. Thanks for the help.